# Anyone know about this "unknown class name 'CBCentralManagerDelegate';?" error?

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to add bluetooth function (scan, connect and write) to my existing app (using swift and .mm). I tried few different approaches.

**For example**

https://github.com/RickRedSix/BLE4.0-iOS-Swift-Demo/tree/master/BLEDemo.xcodeproj

https://github.com/amrOmran89/Bluetooth-LowEnergy_iOS_Swift_4)

but no matter what i do it always return to the following error.

Does anyone have experienced this error like this?

[image]

Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: have you imported CoreBluetooth?

Comment: Yes I did. The error is generated in 'projectname-swift.h'

Comment: I can build my app without bluetooth function and I can also build the bluetooth function as an app without error.
However, when I put them together I get this the above error

Comment: quit xcode, delete derived data and then build the project

Comment: @ShubhamMishra, thanks for your reply. What exactly do you mean by derived data?
I tried to create new project from scratch using the same codes but i still had the error.

Comment: you still getting the error?

Comment: Yes I do. Any other suggestion?